# How to create a File object with File.fromUri(Uri.parse(input)) with input as a FFUploadedFile data type?

Tags: flutter, dart, uri, archive-file

I'm trying to create a File object with the method File.fromUri(Uri.parse(uploadedImage)); where the input uploadedImage is an FFUploadedFile data type with data that comes from an image the user uploads. I'm trying to use the code below:

```
File file = File.fromUri(Uri.parse(uploadedImage));
final bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
final archiveFile = ArchiveFile('uploadedImages', bytes.length, bytes);
```

And uploaded image comes in the format: FFUploadedFile(name: 1700600326427000_0.png, bytes: 239701, height: null, width: null, blurHash: null,)

However, when I try to run the above Custom Code, I get the error message: "The argument type 'FFUploadedFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'"

How do I get File.fromUri to work with the FFUploadedFile data type as the input?

Comment: [I already explained to you that using `File.fromUri` is for converting a `file://` URL to a local filesystem path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77525157/#comment136672789_77525157).    If you don't have a `file://` URL, you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering indicates a type mismatch. The `File.fromUri` method expects a `String` as input, which represents the URI of the file. However, you're passing an `FFUploadedFile` object directly.

To resolve this, you'll need to use the properties of the `FFUploadedFile` object to retrieve the necessary information, such as the bytes or the file path, and then create a `File` object.

Look at bellow code segment,

```
// Assuming 'uploadedImage' is an instance of FFUploadedFile
Uint8List bytes = uploadedImage.bytes; // Retrieve bytes from FFUploadedFile

// Create a temporary file using the bytes
File tempFile = await _createTemporaryFile(bytes, uploadedImage.name);

// Function to create a temporary file from bytes
Future<File> _createTemporaryFile(Uint8List bytes, String fileName) async {
  Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  String tempPath = tempDir.path + '/' + fileName;
  File tempFile = File(tempPath);
  await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  return tempFile;
}

// Now you can proceed to use the 'tempFile' as needed
final bytesFromFile = await tempFile.readAsBytes();
final archiveFile = ArchiveFile('uploadedImages', bytesFromFile.length, bytesFromFile);
```

This code assumes you have access to the `FFUploadedFile` properties such as `bytes` and `name` to retrieve the necessary information to create a temporary file using `File`. Then, you can perform operations on this temporary file as required.